# Assign action in Rails based on the rank in .order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Scoreboard controller, I am setting an order, and I am stack ranking the results by `score`:

```
 @Quizzes = Quiz.where(finished: true, category: session[:category]).order(score: :desc).limit(10)
```

That returns a table of the top 10 results in a table. I now want to put a message next to the first place (top ranked) result and a different message for the rest of the results. So I tried to create an if/else using `first!`:

```
  <% if Quiz.where(category: session[:category]).first! %>
     <td>You win</td>
  <% else %>
    <td>You lose</td>
  <% end %>
```

This does add "You win" to the view, but it is doing it for the final result (#10) and the `else` message is not appearing at all. I tried switching it to `.last` as well, but the same thing happened.

Assuming you can use `.order` as a way to pick a result, how should I adapt this?

**UPDATE**

Adding full code for rendering the score table:

```
  <% @quizzes do |quiz| %>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><%= quiz.user.username %></td>
     <td><%= quiz.user.city %></td>
     <td><%= quiz.category %></td>
     <td><%= quiz.score %></td>
     <% end %>

  <% @quizzes.each_with_index do |quiz, index| %>
    <% if index == 10 %>
        <td>You Win</td>
     <% else %>
        <td>You lose</td>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</tr>
```

Comment: why not using `.each` to iterate over them?

Comment: I am currently using `.each` to iterate for the results in the table. So currently, I would have a table showing results 1-10 based on score (what you see in the controller). For the top ranked row, I want to show a special message as the final column. For the other 9 results, I also want to show a different message. My belief with `.each` is that it couldn't let me customize like that. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you should do:

```
<% @quizzes.each_with_index do |quiz, index| %>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><%= quiz.user.username %></td>
     <td><%= quiz.user.city %></td>
     <td><%= quiz.category %></td>
     <td><%= quiz.score %></td>
     <% if index == 0 %>
        <td>You Win</td>
     <% else %>
        <td>You lose</td>
     <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This makes sense to me logically, but it is appending the messages all in the final row again (like before) and actually putting all of the messages in the same row (so the winner message followed by 9 loser messages). Changing it to `if index == 10`does not change the result, so I do not think it is querying the index right now.

Comment: It sounds like the issue is with the html then. Can you post that in your question?

Comment: Yes this is because you are iterating over all the results again in this loop. You should change your first loop with the code i give. Alternatively, if you post all the code for rendering table then i can correct it to solve your issue.

Comment: @aliibrahim good point. Just updated with all the code for rendering that table.

Comment: @darkginger I just updated my answer. Please try this one

Comment: Works perfectly. Selecting as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<% @Quiz.each do |quiz| %>
  <% if quiz == @Quiz.first %>
    <td>You win</td>
  <% else %>
    <td>You win</td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As .first returns the first object of a collection, not whether or not the object is the first object. That being said you could also do:

```
<% @Quiz.each_with_index do |quiz, index| %>
```

And just check whether index == 0 to determine if it is the first object.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the ten scores in `@top_ten = Quiz.where(finished: true, category: session[:category]).order(score: :desc).limit(10)`

You can do the following:

```
<% @top_ten.each_with_index do |quiz, index| %>
    <% if index == 0 %>
        <td>You Win</td>
    <% else %>
        <td>You lose</td>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```